# Is state machine based sequence detector easier to verify than shift register based one?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra, vlsi, state-machines

Suppose I have two versions of sequence detectors: one is based on let's say Moore machine and the other one is based on simple shift register & comparator. Which one among these is easy to verify and scalable?

Comment: A shift register **is** a state machine.

Comment: its the same thing

Comment: could you please elaborate on how? Recently I was asked this question in one of the interviews and the interviewer told me state machine based one is easier and I couldn't understand how.

Comment: @pcs The state machine one is easier for me because the states are meaningful to me. But that's an opinion not a proof. My suggestion is that you take something reasonably non-trivial and where it has an obvious path for extension and then you create both implementations on your own for the simpler non-trivial case before extending it. Then take the next step and move to a new scale with it and re-implement both. I suspect that all you need to know will come from this experience -- regardless of where it takes you, you'll be in a much better position the next time this kind of question arises.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run an FSM, you must have a register that stores the current state of the FSM.

If you only want to recognise a specific sequence, a shift register is both verifiable and scalable. Even if your sequence is of undeterminate length, you will effectively need a shift register to parse each specifics of the sequence, resulting in the need for counters, flags, etc.

In practice, most sequences are of a specific length, which means that the task of recognition of more complex patterns within the sequences themselves is delegated to higher-level hardware.

Most likely, you might use a shift register to parse some length of the sequence and pass that on to an FSM that takes care of interpreting the sequence itself.

For example:

- A shift register and comparator combination is more capable of recognising a simple specific pattern like `the first bit of this sequence is zero`, or `The expected input is a specific bit sequence`.
- A FSM is more flexible in recognising more abstract patterns with multiple input and branching results, like the key sequence in a pocket calculator: `while numbers are pressed keep first operand and add next digit; operation set: next number is second operand; while numbers are pressed keep second operand and add next digit; equal button pressed: calculate answer, show it to the screen and set result as first operand`

However big the complexity, though, a FSM is still implemented through shift registers.